# How to check a checkbox with microsoft uiautomation?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I need to automate the madvr gui and enable smooth motion with uiautomation.
But can't find recent and easy working samples.

[image]

The madvr window identification:

[image]

The madvr smooth motion checkbox identification:

[image]

My actual code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MadAutomation
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enabling the madvr smooth motion feature...");

            EnableSmoothMotion();

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void EnableSmoothMotion()
        {
            // Run madvr configuration.         
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\madVR\madHcCtrl.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "editLocalSettingsDontWait";
            p.Start();

            // Enable smooth motion checkbox.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a program that does it. Note you *must* use the NuGet [UIAComWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UIAComWrapper/) package (written by a Microsoft guy) instead of the standard UIAutomation*.dll provided out-of-the-box for it to work. The standard UIA .NET assemblies don't see all AutomationElement, don't know all properties (Aria, etc.).

Yes, it means they are **bugged/obsolete** and for some reason, Microsoft does not officially ship the newer ones with new .NET or Windows releases... Anyway the UIAComWrapper is a 100% source-compatible drop-in replacement, so that shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to see the differences between what's returned by UIAComWrapper vs UIA asssemblies, it's the same differences that you will see if you use **Inspect** (the official UIA tool) vs **UISpy** (the obsolete official UI tool), respectively. They look similar but are in fact quite different in the details or structure.

```
public static void EnableSmoothMotion()
{
    bool finished = false;
    // wait for the settings window to show
    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Children, (sender, e) =>
    {
        var window = (AutomationElement)sender;
        if (window.Current.ClassName != "TFMadVRSettings")
            return;

        // get the tree element
        var tree = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Tree));

        // get the smooth motion element & select it
        var smoothMotion = tree.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "smooth motion"));
        ((SelectionItemPattern)smoothMotion.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern)).Select();

        // get the tab element
        var tab = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Tab));

        // get the pane element
        var pane = tab.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane));

        // get the first checkbox & ensure it's clicked
        var cb = pane.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.CheckBox));
        TogglePattern tp = (TogglePattern)cb.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern);
        if (tp.Current.ToggleState != ToggleState.On) // not on? click it
        {
            ((InvokePattern)cb.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();
        }

        // NOTE: uncomment the two following line if you want to close the window directly
        // get the ok button & push it
        //var ok = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new AndCondition(
        //    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button),
        //    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "OK")));
        //((InvokePattern)ok.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();

        finished = true;
    });

    // run the program
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\madVR\madHcCtrl.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "editLocalSettingsDontWait";
    p.Start();

    while(!finished)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
}
```

Note: I used the event handler here instead of process.MainWindowHandle because the main window for the process is not the settings window, and the settings window is not a child of the main window.

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks! You wrote about Inspect, what about Visual UIA Verify? Is it something wrong with it? This is the soft I used and that you saw in my screenshots.

Comment: Yes VisualUIAVerifyNative is actually similar to inspect, but it's .net (inspect is native), and it does use the UIAComWrapper I mentioned.

Comment: Any particular reason you used `InvokePattern.Invoke()` rather than `TogglePattern.Toggle()` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - huh... no, elements may support more than one pattern. I probably just used the most generic one :-)